# not repeating directory structure in cmake include

Tags: cmake

I have the following folder structure:

```
Project
|-Sources
|  |-Package1
|    |-Component11
|      |-include
|        |-header.hpp
|      |-src
|        |-source.cpp
|      |-CMakeLists.txt
|    |-Component12
|       |-include
|        |-header.hpp
|      |-src
|        |-source.cpp
|      |-CMakeLists.txt
|    |-CMakeLists.txt
|  |-Package2
|    |-Component21
|      |-...
|    |-Component22
|      |-...
|    |-CMakeLists.txt
|  |-CMakeLists.txt
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

Lets say that in this design the `component21` have a dependency on `component11`.
I would like to include the header files of `component11` in this component as:
`#include<Project/Package1/Component11/header.hpp>` without repeating this path in `include` folder of `component11` by creating sub directories there. Is there a way in cmake that i can achieve this?

Comment: In general, no: there is no approach that I'd recommend. Afaik this functionality is not supported by compilers. You could create a include structure in the build directory with the appropriate structure, and copy everything over via custom commands, but this will get you into trouble with the ide, since any navigation to header files would get you to the copied files, not to the originals that should be edited instead. On linux you could create symlinks to the dirs to avoid this issue.

Comment: The fact that you currently cannot use the include paths for public headers of a library in the library itself should be a big red flag tough...